# D3js. Working with classes

Tags: class, d3.js, pie-chart

I am playing around with pie charts in d3.js. I want to have several charts working at the same time, and be able to select one or another by their class. The idea is that there is a main chart, and by clicking in the diferent areas, new charts should emerge displaying sub-categories.
Here's the piece of code that is giving me a headache:

```
        // myPie has been deffined previously as --> var myPie = d3.layout.pie();
        // dataPie is an array such as --> [2,3,1,2]
        // level2 is just an array of arrays containing the sub-sets of data I want to display in the pie-charts

        var myArcs = mySvg.selectAll("g")            
                        .data(myPie(dataPie))
                        .enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class","arc")
                        .attr("transform","translate(" + xCenter +"," + yCenter + ")" )

        // Appending other arcs
        for(i=0; i<allData.length; i++){
            var dataLabels_i = [];
            var dataPie_i = [];                
            for(j=0; j<level2[i].length; j++){
                dataLabels_i[j] = level2[i][j][0]
                dataPie_i[j] = level2[i][j][1]                    
            }
            var arcArray =[];  
            var rectArray =[];  

            arcArray[i] = mySvg.selectAll("g")
                            .data(myPie(dataPie_i))
                            .enter()
                            .append("g")
                            .attr("class","arc_"+i)
                            .attr("transform","translate(" + xCenter +"," + yCenter + ")" )
        }
```

The first piechart is generated nicely (it's ploted later on), but the charts that I generate in the for loop won't. I suspect that it has to do with the fact that I am generating "g's" in an svg that already has some "g's", so there is some sort of conflict and they override? I try to cope with this by assigning different classes to each chart. 
Any idea?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Add this in a working fiddle.

Comment: As @Cyril mentions, tough to answer this one without a little more *working* code but at first glance, your `mySvg.selectAll("g").data(...` is very problematic.  This tells `d3` to find the `g`s  in your svg and compute a selection.  Since the first plot appends `g`s the second plot is going to select those instead of appending a new one.  You need something unique like `mySVG.selectAll('.arc_' + i).data(...`

Answer (score 0):

As Mark mentioned, while trying to generating charts for the loop, you should use a more specific selector instead of using the general `g` selector, such as `"arc_" + i` if that's the different classes you want to assign.

The reason why using `<g>` selector doesn't generate a new chart is that when you `selectAll("g")` and bind data by `myPie(dataPie_i)` in the loop, d3 will find the previous `g` generated from the first piechart, therefore the `enter()` selection won't be updated, it's empty in this case, `<g>` won't be appended. More details about join data can be found [here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).